# how to properly match data in awk and fill in missind data based on a known date/time file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data study running from 1/1/2002 00:00 to 12/31/19 23:00. Not all location have the same time ranges thus to make data processing easier I have a script to fill in the missing dates YYYYMMDD and HH:MM times. I have happened to notice the script is not transferring the data exactly correct. I am processing this data using awk scripting. Here is example data input ....

```
01:00,20020101,0.003
02:00,20020101,0.002
03:00,20020101,0.003
04:00,20020101,0.002
05:00,20020101,0.001
```

This is then fed to temp1.tmp which gives the correct values ....

```
20020101 0.003
20020101 0.002
20020101 0.003
20020101 0.002
20020101 0.001
```

However when attempting to match col 1 to identify missing data in temp1 and matching to the correct date/time row the temp2.tmp file gives....

```
20020101 0.013
20020101 0.013
20020101 0.013
20020101 0.013
20020101 0.013
```

These values are not even close to correct. 0.013 data point does not even occur until the 09:00 hour measurement. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful with this script. Thank you

```
#Print the column information
awk -F ',' '{print $2,$3}'  County081-O3-0124.txt > temp1.tmp
awk  'NR==FNR {missing[$1]=$2} NR>FNR {printf("%s %s\n",$1,missing[$1]);}' temp1.tmp 2002-2019yyyymmdd.txt > temp2.tmp
# Print data column for MODIS data
awk '{print $2}' temp2.tmp > temp3.tmp
# Fill blank data spots with missing data flag of -99
awk '{print NF?$1:blankrow}' blankrow=-999 temp3.tmp > temp4.tmp
        cp 2002-2019yyyymmdd-hhmm.txt  temp5.tmp
        paste temp5.tmp temp4.tmp > temp6.tmp
#    sed -i 's/-28672.0000/-999/g' temp6.tmp
#    sed -i 's/0.0000/-999/g' temp6.tmp
#    sed -i 's/-999000/-999/g' temp6.tmp
    sed -i 's/\t/,/g' temp6.tmp
     mv temp6.tmp test.out
```

Comment: your question is very hard to understand and it's unclear what are asking. please [edit] to revise your given sample input (it's an incomplete sample I think) and the expected output and explain the criteria how input should transform to your expected output and explain what is the problem with your current script that you asked for help.

Comment: It looks to me like you are attempting to use `missing[$1]=$2` to store all of the `$2` values from temp1.tmp to then reference $1 in 2002-2019yyyymmdd.txt and print the value from `missing[]` for that `$1`, but the value for `$1` in temp1.tmp can repeat. So what you're doing is changing the value for `missing[$1]` every time `$1` is the same value as it was for a previous record. My guess is the last value for `$2` in temp1.tmp when  `$1` = 20020101 is 0.013. Every time `$1` = 20020101 in 2002-2019yyyymmdd.txt you are printing `missing[20020101]`, which is the value `0.013`.

Comment: Why not stand the problem on its head? Use `seq` to generate all the minutes between the start and end dates (525960 of them), use `date --date=$d "+%....` to format dates (Read `man date`). Then, as you step through the file (and the list of minutes) you'll know when a minute is missed.